# Postgres query that shows the results from 2 columns with the highest counts per month

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-crosstab

I have a database with about 2500 results from 2022. I'm trying to build queries that will show me the top `industry` and `country` results from each month throughout the entire year. The preferred output would include the top X (number) of each category. I'm fine with breaking this out into two queries, one for each category, if needed.

The table looks like this:

```
post_id int
post_date date
post_victim text
threat_group text
victim_industry text
victim_country text
```

The idea here is that I can use these queries to put together data to brief teammates or generate graphs for visualizing the resulting data.

Here's an example of what I'd like to output via a SQL query (shortened to just Jan-Apr, but the final result should cover the entire year):

| Industry | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Healthcare | 95 | 79 | 58 | 12 |
| Manufacturing | 45 | 90 | 72 | 65 |
| Finance | 31 | 48 | 21 | 73 |
| Education | 63 | 70 | 46 | 92 |
| Technology | 86 | 34 | 99 | 25 |
| Construction | 53 | 73 | 16 | 29 |
| Retail | 70 | 90 | 95 | 73 |
| Government | 95 | 73 | 21 | 58 |
| Agriculture | 34 | 53 | 61 | 99 |
| Transportation | 60 | 89 | 22 | 38 |
| Hospitality | 70 | 38 | 96 | 79 |
| Legal | 89 | 67 | 92 | 43 |

I tried using crosstab and specifying the following as `ct (...`:

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  $$
  SELECT to_char(post_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, victim_industry, count(*)
  FROM ransomware_posts
  WHERE post_date >= '2022-01-01' AND post_date < '2023-01-01'
  GROUP BY month, victim_industry
  ORDER BY month, count DESC
  $$
) as ct (month text, industry_1 text, count_1 int, industry_2 text, count_2 int)
```

I think the issue may have something to do with the fact that there are more than 2 results per month, so the output is receiving more results than it's expecting, but I don't know for sure as I've never built a functioning crosstab query.

Here's the error I receive:

```
ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
SQL state: 42601
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message comes from a gap between the structure resulting ffrom the internal query and the structure returned by the crosstab function.

This query should work :

```
SELECT *
FROM crosstab($$
  SELECT victim_industry, to_char(post_date, 'YYYY-MM') :: text as month, count(*) :: int
  FROM ransomware_posts
  WHERE post_date >= '2021-01-01' AND post_date < '2022-01-01'
  GROUP BY victim_industry, month
  ORDER BY victim_industry, month $$
) as ct (industry text, Jan int, Feb int, Mar int, Apr int, May int, Jun int, Jul int, Aug int, Sep int, Oct int, Nov int, Dec int)
```

**UPDTATE**

`crosstab` doesn't manage well the gaps if any.

There is another solution which relies on a `composite type` and the standard function `jsonb_populate_record` :

First creating a dedicated composite type :

```
CREATE TYPE months AS (jan int, feb int, mar int, apr int, jun int, jul int, aug int, sep int, oct int, nov int, dec int)
```

Then the following query provides the expected result :

```
SELECT r.victim_industry, (jsonb_populate_record(null :: months, jsonb_object_agg(lower(r.date), r.count))).*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT victim_industry, to_char(post_date, 'Mon') AS date, count(*) AS count
         FROM ransomware_posts
        WHERE post_date >= '2021-01-01' AND post_date < '2022-01-01'
        GROUP BY victim_industry, to_char(post_date, 'Mon')
    ) AS r
GROUP BY r.victim_industry
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/n_mf7juA)

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a null result. It starts each row at the earliest month with entries. For example, in the real data set there is a month where there are no results for Automotive. The results for the Automotive industry all shift so that `null` appears in December, even though there are 8 entries for December in the data.

Comment: yes this is the standard behiavor of `crosstab` : "The crosstab function produces one output row for each consecutive group of input rows with the same row_name value. It fills the output value columns, left to right, with the value fields from these rows. If there are fewer rows in a group than there are output value columns, the extra output columns are filled with nulls; if there are more rows, the extra input rows are skipped." see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.52.5)

Comment: I can provide you an other solution without the crosstab function, I will update my answer

Comment: I see the edits made, this seems to make sense. One question I would have (thanks so much, by the way, this is awesome) would be whether this could be generalized enough so that I could re-run the query referencing another column from the table, such as victim_country, instead of victim_industry. I assume I would need to build a different type? Or could the type be created with a generic term in place of victim_industry in the example code you provided?

Comment: In fact it is possible to put `victim_industry` out of the composite type. It is even more simple, and makes the composite type reusable for `victim_country`. See my answer updated.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! Marked as `answered`!!